# Absolute Error as a tool to evaluate model

Tags: r, regression, logistic, goodness-of-fit

I want to predict a binary response variable `y` using logistic regression. `x1` to `x4` are the log  of continuous variables and `x5` to `x7` are binary variables.

```
Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + 
    x6 + x7, family = binomial(), data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.6604  -0.5712   0.4691   0.6242   2.4095  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -2.84633    0.31609  -9.005  < 2e-16 ***
x1             0.14196    0.04828   2.940  0.00328 ** 
x2             4.05937    0.22702  17.881  < 2e-16 ***
x3            -0.83492    0.08330 -10.023  < 2e-16 ***
x4             0.05679    0.02109   2.693  0.00709 ** 
x5             0.08741    0.18955   0.461  0.64467    
x6            -2.21632    0.53202  -4.166  3.1e-05 ***
x7             0.25282    0.15716   1.609  0.10769    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1749.5  on 1329  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1110.5  on 1322  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1126.5

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

The output of the GLM shows that most of my variables are significant for my model, but the various goodness of fit test I have done:

```
anova <- anova(model, test = "Chisq")   # Anova
1 - pchisq(sum(anova$Deviance, na.rm = TRUE),df = 7) # Null Model vs Most Complex Model
1 - pchisq(model$null.deviance - model$deviance, 
           df = (model$df.null - model$df.residual )) # Null Deviance - Residual Deviance ~ X^2
hoslem.test(model$y, model$fitted.values, g = 8)     # Homer Lemeshow test
pR2(model)                                            # Pseudo-R^2
```

tell me that there is a lack of evidence to support my model.

More over, I have a bimodal deviance plot. I suspect the bimodal distribution is caused by the sparsity of my binary variables.
 [image]

So I calculated the absolute error `abs(y - y_hat)`, and obtained the following:

- 77% of my absolute errors were in [0;0.25], which I think is very good!

On the following plot, Y=1 is red, and Y=0 is green. This model is better at predicting when Y will be 1 than 0.

[image]

My question is thus the following:

The goodness of fit tests all assume that my null hypothesis follows a Chi square distribution of some sort. Is it correct to conclude that based on my absolute error, my model's prediction is OK, it's just that it doesn't follow a Chi square distribution and thus perform poorly with these tests?